# How to handle Error after moved to Hyperforce

Tags: salesforce

I got err when i try to make API callout from apex class.

This error :

The remote host or network may be down or blocking requests from publicproxy.  Please verify acls at the origin  tzr.pbx.voicespin.com(212.179.131.205 - not real Ip)

Check with destination team if they have implemented some allow-listing mechanism. Note: If  destination endpoint  is hosted on ingress gateway ( managed-mesh-support ) can guide if they are blocking requests.

In case of no issues at destination team, check the destination firewall/security groups for access. Reach out to soter-support for assistance

Reach out to the slack channel outbound_access if the issue persists

aws-prod17-eunorth1/core1

client: 10.132.242.171(not real Ip) (POST) --> (proxy) -X-> tzr.pbx.voicespin.com(212.179.131.205:80)

Details:

```
[unknown]
```

error: (110) Connection timed out

Generated Wed, 28 Feb 2024 09:32:12 GMT by secureproxy.net.salesforce.com (squid)

This happen right after we moved to Hyperforce